# Running xinetd and httpd on centos 6

Tags: centos, apache-httpd, xinetd

We are running several centos 6.4 lamp stacks, and our backup solution (unitrends) has a client that requires xinetd.

Can these two coexist on the same server? If so, is there any secret handshake I need to perform to keep xinetd from assuming the work of Apache?

Or am I worrying about nothing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Xinetd and standalone servers can coexist without problems. Just check /etc/xinetd.d/ for the servers that are under xinetd and set to "enabled=no" the servers you want to keep standalone.